# Progressive Enhancement with Yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2, progressive-enhancement

I am trying to make my website work with both js enbaled and when it's not. I've just started. So I'm starting with the registration of a new user. I have a link to register and it works fine.

I also have a JS version where the form is in a modal box.

user controller

```
/**
* register via modal box
*/
public function actionJsRegister()
{
    // get js modal #id
    $js = '$("#create").modal("show")';
    // register js code
    $this->getView()->registerJs($js); 

    $model = new User();
    $userType = $model->getUserTypeDropDown();  

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        // set flash
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Account Created, please check your inbox');
        // send activation email
        return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
    } else {    
        return $this->render('jsCreate', [
            'model' => $model,
            'userType' => $userType,
        ]);
    }
}
```

1 - Is that controller ok as code?

2 - How would I make my link in the navbar show just the regular version if no js is enabled and the modal version if it is enabled?

Comment: Why waste your time?  Either use a framework that has this built in or don't bother.  Everyone has javascript enabled now.

Comment: Toby: Whether or not someone has support for JS isn't the point. On the web, you don't control the execution environment. So many things can cause your JavaScript based application to not perform well at work correctly (network issues, firewalls, user preferences, device limitations like RAM, processor speed, etc.)… Believing everyone can get your JavaScript (or even your CSS or web fonts) is just naïve. It's far better to build a robust experience that will work no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to you for building with progressive enhancement! Your site will be far more robust for it.

I can't speak specifically for the controller code as I have not used Yii2 (though logically it looks sensible), but I can discuss the second question about the navigation. The easiest way to do it is to have the navbar exist by default and then use JavaScript to hijack the page, converting the navbar into a modal.